# PHP Data from MySQL into Separate Pages per Entry

Tags: php, mysql

I am pulling information from the database into a .php page. I want the information to sit as separate entries (all questions / answers together, followed by the next set of answers) rather than in a table. My form is long so having everything in a table like I have it will make it incredibly long. How do I change this? I know I have it setup in at table, but i'm not sure how to change it to separate items.

What would be even more great (although I suspect very difficult) is to have the user click on a line that shows the ID and date_visit only, which will take them to a separate page with that completed form results. So to view each form as a separate page, almost. I expect this may be very complex though?

Am very new to using databases. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

 // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM survey";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Store Name</th><th>Receipt #</th><th>Date of Store Visit</th></tr>";
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["ID"]."</td><td>".$row["storename"]."</td><td>".$row["receipt"]."</td><td>".$row["date_visit"]."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: You just make link like `echo sprintf(<a href="view.php?id=%s">View Response</a>', $row['ID']);` and then in you view.php you would get all the questions/answers for that `survey.ID` and display them however you want. Can't give you any advice on the display part really because you didn't include any of your SQL for that part of it.

Comment: Thank you. What part of the SQL do you need to see?

Comment: Well what SQL do you run to display all the questions answers in a table?

Comment: The code that I had pasted above....

Comment: But that just outputs some summary data it doesnt give me any clue as to what the other fields are on the table, or if you should actually be pulling from a different table or multiple other tables (normally something like this would be set up across several tables like `survey`, `survey_answer`, `survey_question`).

Comment: Thank you, I just learnt how to do databases so it appears I may need to go and do some more learning. At the moment I just have the 3 fields 'id', 'storename' and 'receipt', i'm not pulling from any other table but it sounds like I maybe should.

Comment: Oh well then what did you mean by "*separate page with that completed form results*"? What are the other results?

Comment: I just mean having each persons entry as a separate page. So User 1 sends in the form and I click to view that and it loads its own page. Then User 2 sends in the form and I click to view that as a separate page. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Im not sure what you are doing at all your set seems to only contain 4 pieces of data so why you would want to click through to see the remaining 2 columns is beyond me.

That said here is what you would do essentially (*note: I have not tested any of this so there may be some syntax errors - its not cut/paste code, but it should illustrate the basics of what you are asking to do*)...

So `list.php` will essentially be the same as what you have now only we will add a link as i mentioned in my comment:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// only selecting the fields you need is generally better
// its also a good practice to get into aliasing your tablenames
// and always using the table_or_alias.column_name to reference them
$sql = "SELECT s.ID, s.date_vist FROM survey s";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result === false) {
   die(sprintf(
      'An error occurred attempting to access the data: "%s"',
      $conn->error
   ));
}
?>

<?php if ($result->num_rows > 0): ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Date of Store Visit</th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php while (false !== ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['ID'] ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['date_visit'] ?></td>
                    <td>
                       <?php pritntf(
                           '<a href="view.php?id=%s">View Details</a>', 
                           echo $row['ID']
                       ); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php else: ?>
   <p>0 Results</p>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php $conn->close(); ?>
```

Now for you `view.php` you will take the parameter `id` from the URL and use it to select the full info from the DB.

```
<?php

    $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (integer) $_GET['id'] : null;
    if (null === $id) {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found", true, 404);
        exit;
    }

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// we will us a prepared statment to avoid SQL injection
// when use a ? to mark a placeholder for a value in the query
$sql = 'SELECT s.* FROM survey s WHERE s.ID = ? LIMIT 1';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

if (false === $stmt) {
    die(sprintf(
        'Error attempting to access data: "%s"',
        $conn->error
    ));
}

// bind the ID to the prepared statement
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);

if (!$stmt->execute() || false === ($result = $stmt->get_result())) {
    die(sprintf(
        'Error attempting to access data: "%s"',
        $stmt->error
    ));
} elseif ($result->num_rows < 1) {
    // no results so 404
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found", true, 404);
    exit;

} else {
    $survey = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $labels = array(
        'ID' => 'ID',
        'storename' => 'Store Name',
        'receipt' => 'Receipt #',
        'date_visit' => 'Date of Store Visit'
    );
}

$stmt->close();
$result->close();
?>


<table>
    <tbody>
         <?php foreach($survey as $column => $value): ?>
             <tr>
                 <th><?php echo isset($labels[$column]) 
                         ? $labels[$column] 
                         : ucwords($column); ?>
                 </th>
                 <td><?php echo $value; ?>
             </tr>
         <?php endforeach; ?>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you. I have more than 4 fields, i'm just using 4 for now to test everything. I will give your code above a go.